# Injeção de dependencia de interfaces em Typescript - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, injeção-de-dependência, angular-6

Eu estou fazendo o front-end de um projeto usando Angular 6, porém sou iniciante tanto em Angular quanto em Typescript e estou tentando usar as interfaces do Typescript como no Java, injetando elas para usar os metodos e tals, o problema é o seguinte:

*Eu tenho uma interface com a assinatura dos metodos;

*Eu tenho uma classe q implementa essa interface e tem os metodos;

*Eu tenho um componente q chama a interface no `Contructor` assim `private myInterface: MyInterface` e, pelo menos no Java o que eu faria é fazer esse atributo receber um novo objeto da classe q implementa essa interface (`this.myInterface = new ObjetoQueImplementa();`) e poderia usar seus metodos normalmente, porém no Typescript é diferente, e eu ate vi artigos e alguns exemplos q achei ai com uma certa injeção de dependencia como no Java mas nenhum deles chegou a me ajudar, vou deixar meu código aqui espero q alguem consiga me ajudar aqi.

Interface:

```
import {Agenda} from "../model/agenda";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/index";

export interface AgendaCommandRepository {

  insert(agenda: Agenda): Observable<Agenda>;

  update(agenda: Agenda): Observable<Agenda>;

  deleteAgenda(id: number): Observable<number>;
}
```

Classe que implementa a interface:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AgendaService } from '../service/agenda-command.service';
import { AgendaCommandValidator } from '../validator/agenda-command-
validator';
import { Agenda } from '../../model/agenda';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/index';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl implements AgendaCommandRepository {

  constructor(private service: AgendaService, private validator: 
AgendaCommandValidator) { }

  insert(agenda: Agenda): Observable<Agenda> {

    if (this.validator.validaInsert(agenda)) {
      return this.service.insert(agenda);
    }

    return null;
  }

  update(agenda: Agenda): Observable<Agenda> {

    if (this.validator.validaUpdate(agenda)) {
      return this.service.update(agenda);
    }

    return null;
  }

  deleteAgenda(id: number): Observable<number> {

    if (this.validator.validaDelete(id)) {
      return this.service.deleteAgenda(id);
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Componente que injeta a interface pra chamar os metodos dela e executar o codigo da classe q implementa a interface:

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl } from "../../repository/agenda-
command-repository-impl";
import { Agenda } from "../../../model/agenda";
import { AgendaQueryRepository } from "../../../query/repository/agenda-
query-repository";
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AgendaCommandRepository } from "../../agenda-command-repository";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agenda',
  templateUrl: './agenda-command.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agenda-command.component.css']
})
export class AgendaCommandComponent implements OnInit {

  agenda: Agenda;
  id: number;
  titulo: string; // para teste

  constructor(private repository: AgendaCommandRepository, private 
queryRepository: AgendaQueryRepository, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    if (this.id) {
      this.queryRepository.findById(this.id).subscribe(agenda => this.agenda 
= agenda);
      this.titulo = "Edição";

    } else {
      this.agenda = new Agenda();
      this.titulo = "Cadastro";
    }
  }

  salvar() {

    if (this.id) {
      this.repository.update(this.agenda).subscribe();

    } else {
      this.repository.insert(this.agenda).subscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Sua classe `AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl` não está implementando `AgendaCommandRepository`, apenas tem métodos com o mesmo nome, falta o `implements`. Ao definir no construtor que o tipo é `AgendaCommandRepository` ele tentará usar a interface como valor o que não irá funcionar, você deve passar diretamente a implementação `AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl`

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam me desculpe eu copiei errado, a ideia era ter o `implements` la, nn se preucupe que eu ja editei e concertei meu erro, mas vc tem alguma ideia de como resolver este meu problema?

Comment: Ou você passa `AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl` no construtor ou retira o `private` e dentro instancia a classe `this.repository = new AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl();`

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam pseh eu tentei essa segunda opção e nao deu certo, ele da um erro dizendo que o `this.repository` espera 2 argumentos e esta recebendo 0, na minha concepção era pra funcionar mas como nn entendo mto de typescript a minha concepção nn vale de nada, tem alguma outra ideia?

Comment: Sim, esse erro ocorre porque a classe `AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl` precisa receber dois parametros em seu construtor, você precisa passal-los ao instanciar, quando você cria uma instancia direto nos argumentos do construtor o TS faz isso automático pra ti

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam eu acho q entendi o que vc quis dizer mas, nn tem uma forma mais facil/pratica de se fazer isso? é que desse jeito me parece mto "gambiarrento", fica um codigo mto feio, tipo, o código ficaria assim `this.repository = new AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl(new AgendaService(new HttpClient()), new AgendaCommandValidator());` deve ter algum jeito de fazer isso sem ficar essa gambiarra...

Comment: Sim passar no parâmetro do construtor o a classe que implementa

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam tipo assim `constructor(private repository: AgendaCommandRepository, private repositoryImpl: AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl) { };`?

Comment: pq se for desse jeito nem adianta int, nn quero ter q instanciar o Impl pq senao eu usaria o objeto dele msmo e nn precisaria da interface, eu achei uma forma de fazer exatamente o que eu quero e funciona porem eu peguei de um exemplo de Angular 4 eu acho e tbm esse jeito q eu achei é mto mais trabalhoso e nn sei se vale a pena, [olhe aqui](https://imasters.com.br/front-end/injetando-interfaces-no-typescript) dps de ver esse artigo sera q vc nn sabe um jeito de fazer o resultado daqele artigo sem aquela gambiarra e trabalho todo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda do @GuilhermeCostamilam eu achei a resposta, nn fica tão bonito assim mas da pra usar, ta ai o código:

Interface:

```
import {Agenda} from "../model/agenda";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/index";

export interface AgendaCommandRepository {

  insert(agenda: Agenda): Observable<Agenda>;

  update(agenda: Agenda): Observable<Agenda>;

  deleteAgenda(id: number): Observable<number>;
}
```

Classe que implementa a interface:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AgendaService } from '../service/agenda-command.service';
import { AgendaCommandValidator } from '../validator/agenda-command-validator';
import { Agenda } from '../../model/agenda';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/index';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl implements AgendaCommandRepository {

  private service: AgendaService;
  private validator: AgendaCommandValidator;

  constructor(serviceImpl: AgendaServiceImpl, validatorImpl: AgendaCommandValidatorImpl) {
      this.service = serviceImpl;
      this.validator = validatorImpl;
  }

  insert(agenda: Agenda): Observable<Agenda> {

    if (this.validator.validaInsert(agenda)) {
      return this.service.insert(agenda);
    }

    return null;
  }

  update(agenda: Agenda): Observable<Agenda> {

    if (this.validator.validaUpdate(agenda)) {
      return this.service.update(agenda);
    }

    return null;
  }

  deleteAgenda(id: number): Observable<number> {

    if (this.validator.validaDelete(id)) {
      return this.service.deleteAgenda(id);
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Componente:

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl } from "../../repository/agenda-command-repository-impl";
import { Agenda } from "../../../model/agenda";
import { AgendaQueryRepository } from "../../../query/repository/agenda-query-repository";
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AgendaCommandRepository } from "../../agenda-command-repository";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agenda',
  templateUrl: './agenda-command.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agenda-command.component.css']
})
export class AgendaCommandComponent implements OnInit {

  agenda: Agenda;
  id: number;
  titulo: string; // para teste
  private repository: AgendaCommandRepository;
  private queryRepository: AgendaQueryRepository;

  constructor(repositoryImpl: AgendaCommandRepositoryImpl, queryRepositoryImpl: AgendaQueryRepositoryImpl, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.repository = repositoryImpl;
  this.queryRepository = queryRepositoryImpl;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    if (this.id) {
      this.queryRepository.findById(this.id).subscribe(agenda => this.agenda = agenda);
      this.titulo = "Edição";

    } else {
      this.agenda = new Agenda();
      this.titulo = "Cadastro";
    }
  }

  salvar() {

    if (this.id) {
      this.repository.update(this.agenda).subscribe();

    } else {
      this.repository.insert(this.agenda).subscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

Como o Angular 6 ja faz a injeção da classe pra mim eu só precisei fazer o Angular injetar o Impl(q é o codigo) e fazer a interface receber o Impl, é isso vlw flw!